# Workflow or Process Builder?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, field-update, bestpractice

I'm creating a scenario where upon a Queue change:

1. The resolution (text area) is updated with "XYZ text"
2. The Staff member (ticket owner) is changed to "XYZ user"

Those are technically 2 field updates, which means 2 workflow rules...(right?)

Here are my questions:

1. I can do this in 1 process builder np but should I?-(*because* it's so insignificant?)
2. If I do this in process builder, should I do it using a new process or link it to another process that uses the same object?
3. Is it best practice to keep all of your "workflows" in process builder all under the same roof of that particular object?
4. Is there a time and place to use Workflows instead of Process Builder or are we only suppose to be using Process Builder at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Those are technically 2 field updates, which means 2 workflow rules...(right?)

No, you can include multiple field updates in a single Workflow Rule.

> A. I can do this in 1 process builder np but should I?-(because it's so insignificant?)

Probably.

> B. If I do this in process builder, should I do it using a new process or link it to another process that uses the same object?

Particularly in Process Builder-heavy organizations, it's a common recommendation to maintain exactly one process per object or one process per event per object (insert or update). [Here's](https://medium.com/@apeattie/salesforce-process-builder-best-practices-24e674b2b2b1) one example of a *very* complex and sophisticated Process structure. I'm not sure most orgs need to go that far unless they have a very large amount of automation built in Process Builder, but using a consistent process structure that localizes activity for a single object in one Process can help make your behaviors predictable, testable, and avoid issues with interactions between different automations.

> C. Is it best practice to keep all of your "workflows" in process builder all under the same roof of that particular object?

I am not sure what this means.

> D. Is there a time and place to use Workflows instead of Process Builder or are we only suppose to be using Process Builder at this point?

Sure - use Workflow Rules when you need to send an Outbound Message, which Process Builder cannot do. [There's not a lot that Workflow Rules can do that Process Builder cannot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_which_tool.htm&type=5), and it's easier to keep Processes structured well. They also (in my experience) cause fewer issues in terms of interactions with unsuspecting code.

See also the really good points raised in comments by cropredy and by Prashanth. Process errors provide debugging information (although it can be rather tricky to interpret), and Process Builder + Flow is an area where Salesforce is investing for the future - Workflows are not. There's really no reason to build new Workflow Rules unless you're doing something that explicitly cannot be done in a Process.

Comment: also -- lots of diagnostic info when a PB has an exception is avail to the admin

Comment: Nice.

OP, also please note that Lightning flow (Process Builder + Cloud Flow Designer) is the future. There will be no enhancements to workflows (although there is nothing 'wrong' in its current state). https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/workflow_migration/workflow_migration_intro

Comment: C. Is it best practice to keep all of your "workflows" in process builder all under the same roof of that particular object?

"I am not sure what this means."

I have an Object called "Incident" and currently we have 3 different Processes in Process Builder for that Object. My question is, should I cram all of those different processes into one process because they are the same object or should I keep them separated accordingly? I'm trying to figure out if I should only have 1 process per object or if it's SOP to have multiple processes for one object?

Comment: @DeathStarSurvivor I aimed to cover that under (B); sorry that I misread which part of the question was which.